# Optimized way to populate data in a object

Tags: java

I am working on a solution where I need to populate certain fields in a DataObject, though fields are predefined but source from where I need to populate this data is not in my control and I can not do any modification or changes.

This is a structure of my Source Object

```
SourceObject
   -Collection<Features>
           -Collection<FeatureData>
```

Attribute Name is defined in `SourceObject` which will help me to decided if I want that attribute value or not (There are many attributes (`Framework Provided + Custom one`)) and Value is being provided from `Collection<FeatureData>`

```
    for(SourceData sourceData : productData.getSourceData())
     {
      if(sourceData.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("classification"))
         {
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(sourceData.getFeatures()))
                  {
                      for(FeatureData featureData : sourceData.getFeatures()){

                      if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(featureData.getFeatureValues())){

                  if(featureData .getCode().contains("customValue1")){

                  for(FeatureValueData featureDataValue: featureData.getFeatureValues()){

                productData.setPower(featureDataValue.getValue()));
                    break;
            }
          }
        }
        break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

But that means I have to do this (Check and Fill) for all my custom attributes. Is there way I can handle it in good way ?.
Please do not pay much attention to syntax or any potential NPE etc, as I will going to take care of those issues

Comment: The deeply nested line `if(sourceData.getCode().contains("customValue1"))` looks fishy. If you place it at the very top where you are doing the `sourceData.getCode()` type of filtering, you'll end up with a more understandable code. The presence of two `break`s without any conditions tends to nullify the use of some `for` loops that you've used. If you can explain in more detail as to what exactly the whole code is like, perhaps I can help in getting your code cleaned and making it efficient. Is the `sourceData` too much? Cause then we can also take advantage of parallel code.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri: my mistake...correcting my question now

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri: source data is basically having information of complete classification system.I have corrected my code, We will only get values from sourceData if that is of our customType as we will ignore any framework provided data

Comment: The presence of your second `break` means that if the very first `featureData`'s `featureValues` is empty, the loop will effectively quit. Is that what you really intend to do? And is the code working all fine? You just want a cleaned up version of your code, right?

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri: Yes, second break just to make sure..that once i fill value I do not want to iterate at all...actually for our custom attribute..second collection will always contain one element.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can comprehend from your code is that you are trying to find the very first `sourceData` whose `code` matches the `"classification"` value and also whose `features` collection isn't empty.

Then once such `sourceData` is found, you are trying to find the very first `feature` from the `sourceData`'s `features` collection whose `code` contains the `"customValue1"` in it and whose `featureValueData` collection isn't empty.

Once such `feature` is found, you are effectively setting the `productData`'s `power` as the value that is held by the very first `featureValueData` of the `featureValueData` collection of the `feature`.

Such code can be rewritten as follows:

```
// Start
SourceData sourceData = findFirstValidSource(productData.getSourceData());

if (sourceData == null) // Can remove this check if sure that at least one valid source data will always exist.
{
  return;
}

FeatureData feature = findFirstValidFeature(sourceData.getFeatures());

if (feature == null) // Can also remove this check if sure that at least one valid feature data will always exist.
{
  return;
}

FeatureValueData featureValueData = feature.getFeatureValues().iterator().next();
productData.setPower(featureValueData.getValue());
// End
```

The `findFirstValidSource()` method is implemented as follows:

```
private SourceData findFirstValidSource(Collection<SourceData> sources)
{
  for (SourceData source : sources)
  {
    if (source.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("classification") && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(source.getFeatures()))
    {
      return source;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

The `findFirstValidFeature()` method is implemented as follows:

```
private FeatureData findFirstValidFeature(Collection<FeatureData> features)
{
  for (FeatureData feature : features)
  {
    if (feature.getCode().contains("customValue1") && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(feature.getFeatureValues()))
    {
      return feature;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

The above code will also do the exact same thing that your code is doing, except that its more readable and understandable now. The code can save some more processing if you make your `getFeatureValues()` method return a `List` instead of a `Collection`, as then it can grab the very first element through indexing (if implementation is `ArrayList` based) or by getting the first element (if implementation is `LinkedList` based), which will take constant time.
Not that the `iterator().next()` takes any more time, it just is useless to create an iterator in this case when there's no requirement of it as I did in the line:

```
FeatureValueData featureValueData = feature.getFeatureValues().iterator().next();
```

If `getFeatureValues()` would have returned a `List`, we could have written:

```
FeatureValueData featureValueData = feature.getFeatureValues().get(0);
```

instead.

Furthermore, the code can be made more compact by use of Lambda Expressions and Streams which are introduced in JDK 8. If you have no issues using the new features of Java 8, I can update my answer to incorporate a terser solution as well.

Let me know if my answer helped or if your expectations are still not met.